# Inverse Function of $ \frac{1}{2} ( e^x - e^{-x} ) $

Tags: inverse

Should find the inverse of:

$$  f(x) = \frac{1}{2} ( e^x - e^{-x} ) $$

I tried a lot. But I don't know how to proceed on $$ 2x = \frac{(e^y)^2 - 1}{e^y} $$

Writing $ e^{-y} $ as $ \frac{1}{e^y} $ is right? I know somewhere I need to use the $ ln $ but I dont know when

Comment: $\operatorname{arsinh} (x) = \ln \left(x + \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} \right)$

Comment: @Henry That is wonderfully enlightening.

Comment: @Did: It provides a check at the end.  It also suggests the negative root of the quadratic needs a little thought

Comment: @Henry "Suggests"?? How? I see no suggestion of this sort, just a flat formula.

Comment: @Did: as in *Silver Blaze*. Sherlock Holmes: "... the curious incident of the dog in the night-time." Inspector Gregory: "The dog did nothing in the night-time." Sherlock Holmes: "That was the curious incident."

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Student[Calculus1]):
InverseTutor(1/2*(exp(x)-exp(-x)), x = -10 .. 10);
 $$ produces [the output](http://rapidshare.com/files/1015802594/inverse.docx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantity $z=\mathrm e^y$ solves the quadratic $z^2-2xz-1=0$. Surely you can write down the roots of the quadratic and from there, deduce $y$ (just remember that $z\gt0$).

Comment: what is $ z^2 - 2xy - 1 = 0 $ and how would you come up with that?

Comment: You know that $2x=((\mathrm e^y)^2-1)/\mathrm e^y$ and you decide to rename $\mathrm e^y$ as $z$. Hence $2x=(z^2-1)/z$, right? Hence...

Comment: ah. now i know where u want to "direct" me. the typical root formula. thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Note the word "quadratic". Either you know the formula for the roots of any quadratic, or you note that the equation to solve is also $z^2-2xz+x^2-x^2-1=0$, that is, $(z-x)^2=$ $____$ hence...

Comment: know i just take the formula i know from highschool to solving roots. pretty simple and i get $ z_1 = 2 + \sqrt{x^2 + 1} $ and $ z_2 = 2 - \sqrt{x^2+1} $

Comment: Please have a fresh look at "the formula [you] know from highschool", the one you used is wrong.

Comment: oh yeah. miscalculated! you're right! but if i have 2 roots then, so is this proof for not having a true inversional function? or do i have 2 functions for negative and positve x?

Comment: You do have two roots but you know that $z\gt0$ since $z$ is a real exponential hence you know which root is "your" $z$. (This was explained at the very end of my answer, no?)

Comment: z is > 0 because e^x never gets below 0? or why?

Comment: Yes (not "or why").

Answer (score 4):

Let $e^x=z$. Thus, you have:

$$y=\frac{1}{2} (z-\frac{1}{z})$$

Solve the resulting quadratic for $z$ and then set $x = ln(z)$.

Comment: that could work. is that the only way to solve it? or is it just easier?

Comment: I am guessing you know how to solve a quadratic equation. Use that knowledge to solve for $z$.

Comment: @Dominique: It is a quadratic equation so use a standard formula or complete the square

Comment: yeah. math is seing the "matrix". in that case I wouldn't expect a quadratic equation :)